# SVG pattern fill position from top right, instead of top left

Tags: html, css, svg, fill

Is it possible to assign the starting point of the svg pattern fill from top right instead of top left?

For instance, CSS has `background-position` but I'm having trouble finding an SVG alternative which allows the same functionality.

Here's a CSS example of what I'm trying to achieve with SVG pattern fill: https://jsfiddle.net/19bc20p6/

And this is how far I've gotten with the SVG: https://jsfiddle.net/56cp4xwh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of your blue panel pattern in SVG is as follows:

```html
<svg width="50vw" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="blue" x1="100%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="skyblue"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="navy"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="panel-one" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="20" height="20" x="100%" y="0%">
      <rect width="20" height="20" fill="url(#blue)"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#panel-one)"/>
</svg>
```

The `x` and `y` attributes of the `<pattern>` element effectively set the origin of the pattern. To set it to the top right, you would set it to `x="100%" y="0%"` as I have done here.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is indeed exactly what I need.

Comment: This:

`The x and y attributes of the <pattern> element effectively set the origin of the pattern.`

Was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

s it possible to assign the starting point of the svg pattern fill from top right instead of top left?

> for this use    transform: rotate(0deg);

i think its work

Comment: I resorted to use rotate3d instead, as the 2d rotation transform didn't quite align properly horizontally. Wish there would've been a better way though.